# Create a video form images and videos and add audio to it programatically | Java, Python, ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I want to create a new video (`finalVideo.mp4`) with:

1. 3 image files `image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg`, each image to be seen for 4 seconds
2. 1 video file (`video1.mp4`), lasts for about 30 seconds with a frame rate of 30fps
3. 1 audio file (`audio1.mp3`)

In the final video (`finalVideo.mp4`) I want the audio (`audio1.mp3`) to play only when the images are present and the video's (`video1.mp4`) audio when the video is present.

***For example:***
The final video (`finalVideo.mp4`) contains
`image1.jpg`,
`video1.mp4`,
`image2.jpg` and
`image3.jpg` (in order). The audio (`audio1.mp3`) should play for the first 4 seconds, then the video's (`video1.mp4`) audio for the next 30 seconds and then the audio (`audio1.mp3`) for the next 8 (4*2) seconds.

Please let me know how to do this programmatically. I was hoping to figure this out using Java (JavaCV) or Python (OpenCV). But there is no programming language restriction as such, the answer can be in any language.

---

**EDIT 1**

Here is my attempt at making this work:

```
String ffmpeg = Loader.load(org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class);
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                ffmpeg,
                "-loop", "1",
                "-framerate", "30",
                "-t", "4",
                "-i", "image1.jpg",
                "-i", "video1.mp4",
                "-loop", "1",
                "-framerate", "30",
                "-t", "4",
                "-i", "image2.jpg",
                "-loop", "1",
                "-framerate", "30",
                "-t", "4",
                "-i", "image3.jpg",
                "-filter_complex", "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0",
                "finalVideo.mp4"
        );
        processBuilder.inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

The above code only solves the video creation part without audio. Please let me know how to add audio to this video as stated above.

Comment: OpenCV has nothing about audio, so you may want to look for another library

Comment: @Miki thanks for your reply. Sure, I will look into another library. Any suggestions?

Comment: You picked the right tag. FFmpeg will do the job for you. You can easily find a plethora of examples either here or elsewhere via Google. (See Related section to the right of this post) Post your attempt if you need help using it.

Comment: @kesh I have posted my attempt. I am right now only able to create a video with the images and the video file. I am not sure how to add audio to this as stated above. Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: Almost there. You can do the same to the audio streams. Look at the example in [`concat` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same with the audio, use `-ss` and `-t` input options to control  where to clip it.

```
String ffmpeg = Loader.load(org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class);
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                ffmpeg,
                "-loop", "1",
                "-framerate", "30",
                "-t", "4",
                "-i", "image1.jpg",
                "-i", "video1.mp4",
                "-loop", "1",
                "-framerate", "30",
                "-t", "4",
                "-i", "image2.jpg",
                "-loop", "1",
                "-framerate", "30",
                "-t", "4",
                "-i", "image3.jpg",
                "-t" 4, "-i", "audio1.mp3",
                "-ss" 4, "-t", 8, "audio1.mp3",
                "-filter_complex", 
                "[0][1:v][2][[3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0;[4][1:a][5]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1;",
                "finalVideo.mp4"
        );
        processBuilder.inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

(not 100% if you can use the same input file twice, but this should work.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could solve the problem using this approach!

Comment: Right now, stopping the audio (`audio1.mp3`) after 4 seconds and playing the video's (`video1.mp4`) audio seems very abrupt. It feels like there is a sudden change in the transition of the two audios. Any clue how to make the transition smoother? Maybe like a fade in fade out effect?

Comment: There is a `afade` filter that you can add to your filtergraph, here is [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade-1)